# Linq2Twitter MVC authorization returning null values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, linq-to-twitter

I am using Linq2Twitter in my application (MVC5) to connect to twitter. After authorizing I am getting null values for OAuthTokenSecret, ScreenName and 0 for UserID. I am not able to tweet since I am not having OAuthTokenSecret.

I am using below code...

//To authorize

```
var auth = new MvcAuthorizer
        {
            CredentialStore = new SessionStateCredentialStore
            {
                ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterKey"],
                ConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["twitterSecret"]//,
                //OAuthToken = null,
                //OAuthTokenSecret=null
            }
        };
        return await auth.BeginAuthorizationAsync(redirectUri);
```

//To complete authorization

```
var auth = new MvcAuthorizer
        {
            CredentialStore = new SessionStateCredentialStore()
        };

        auth.CompleteAuthorizeAsync(uri);
        return auth;
```

PS: Authentication code is in Services Layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *await* the call to *CompleteAuthorizeAync*:

```
    await auth.CompleteAuthorizeAsync(uri);
```

The method is returning before the operation completes, meaning that you're examining state that isn't yet available.